# Looking for gis data on world linguistics by location

Tags: geospatial, language

Looking for geospatial information on linguistics.

Looking for world wide data with national and subnational data. Data should include what regions speak which language(s).

Does this data exist?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this data exists for Africa. Here is the link.

http://worldmap.harvard.edu/africamap/

There is a variable under the "Ethno Linguistic" group labeled as Language Families 2001. Hope this piece helps.

The polygons seem to be served from a geoserver. I looked at the HTML and here is an example of a polygon:

```
<img class="olTileImage" src="http://worldmap.harvard.edu/geoserver/wms?STYLES=lang_families_felix&amp;FORMAT=image%2Fpng&amp;TRANSPARENT=TRUE&amp;LAYERS=geonode%3Aetnicity_felix&amp;EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&amp;VERSION=1.1.1&amp;SERVICE=WMS&amp;REQUEST=GetMap&amp;LLBBOX=-17.5337867736816,-31.9347820281982,51.4154243469238,37.3495597839355&amp;URL=http%3A%2F%2Fworldmap.harvard.edu%2Fgeoserver%2Fwms&amp;TILED=true&amp;SRS=EPSG%3A900913&amp;BBOX=3130860.678125,-626172.135625,3757032.81375,-1.0477378964424e-9&amp;WIDTH=256&amp;HEIGHT=256" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 0.82; position: absolute; left: 442%; top: -25%; width: 256%; height: 256%;">
```

Comment: Do you know if this information can be provided as a REST / Feature Service ?

Comment: I am not sure about if this is accessible by a REST endpoint, but there does seem to be a geoserver behind this layer. I can update my response to give an example. You might be able to access the geoserver directly, or you might be able to download the shapefile from this site.